# Modifications done in class library is not reflected in .dll file

Tags: c#, dll, metadata

I have added a new member to already created class library. Whatever New members I have added are not reflecting in .dll file.

For eg I have added new member like the one below:-

```
    private string _TEST = String.Empty;

    public string TEST
    {
        get { return _TEST; }
        set { _TEST = value; }
    }
```

I tried to access this new member in aspx.cs file but couldn't do it.
I have added reference and using directive but still it throws an error message as below in aspx.cs file:-

Type does not contain the definition for 'TEST' and no extension method 'TEST' accepting a first argument as type could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Please confirm that you've rebuild class library and related projects.

Comment: Are you sure the updated version of the DLL is being copied to the IIS server? If you copy the dll off of the server and open it with a decomplier like ILSpy do you see the property?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have rebuild the class library and related projects. Do I need to check Properties of this class library project?